# Writing a Dictionary to a text file in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, regex, dictionary

This is my first post so please forgive me if there are errors/misunderstandings. I'm very new to python and trying to use it to improve and automate my everyday job as an IT technician.

My problem:

I have 15000+ .txt files that have a four-digit number in each file (or not) that I'm using RegEx to retrieve, store in a dictionary, and print. This works well and fine for me! (code for this below)

```
import re, os
from os import listdir

txtfiles = [f for f in listdir("C:\\Users\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\")]

txtlist = {}


for file in txtfiles:
    with open("C:\\Users\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\" + file) as filename:
        for line in filename:
            if re.search('\(\w+\/3\d+@', line):
                entry = re.search('\/(\d+)', line).group(1)
                if entry in txtlist:
                    txtlist[entry] += 1
                else:
                    txtlist[entry] = 1

for key, value in txtlist.items():
    print(key, " : ", value)
```

This prints:

```
3008  :  36
3007  :  64
3015  :  68
3004  :  66
3017  :  32
```

Which is exactly what I want, yay me.

I'm now trying to get this to create a file in the same folder as all the other textfiles that will have the same formatting as the print call. Unfortunately, I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/filepathofpycharmpytonfile", line 25, in <module>
    file.write(key, ' : ', value)
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

Here is my code for the above error:

```
import re, os
from os import listdir

txtfiles = [f for f in listdir("C:\\Users\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\")]

txtlist = {}


for file in txtfiles:
    with open("C:\\Users\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\" + file) as filename:
        for line in filename:
            if re.search('\(\w+\/3\d+@', line):
                entry = re.search('\/(\d+)', line).group(1)
                if entry in txtlist:
                    txtlist[entry] += 1
                else:
                    txtlist[entry] = 1


with open("C:\\Users\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\"1.Results.txt", "x" ) as file:
    for key, value in txtlist.items():
        file.write(key, ' : ', value)
```

So, my question is, how do I write the results to a file in the same way that I printed them to my console?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.
To get around this, I wrote it as a JSON file which worked but obviously didn't keep the formatting I wanted. Please see code below:

```
import re, os
import json
from os import listdir

txtfiles = [f for f in listdir("C:\\Users\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\")]

txtlist = {}


for file in txtfiles:
    with open("C:\\Users\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\" + file) as filename:
        for line in filename:
            if re.search('\(\w+\/3\d+@', line):
                entry = re.search('\/(\d+)', line).group(1)
                if entry in txtlist:
                    txtlist[entry] += 1
                else:
                    txtlist[entry] = 1


with open("C:\\Users\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\Redacted\\1.Results.txt", "x" ) as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(txtlist))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting what you want to write with an f-string:

```
file.write(f'{key} : {value}\n')
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly once I added a '\n':

`file.write(f'{key} : {value}' '\n')`

I will do some reading on f.

Comment: Good shout with the`\n` -- I had forgotten about it.

Comment: I didn't know you could add it directly after the value inside the same ' '. Thanks for the great answer and what I perceive as clean code!

Answer (score 0):

instead of `file.write(key, ' : ', value)` try `file.write(key + ' : ' + value)`

Concatting the strings instead of passing multiple arguments, because as the error states file.write only expexts one argument.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, however, The 'value' throws an error saying "expected type str instead got int." @mrblewog's method worked!

Comment: `file.write(str(key) + ' : ' + str(value))` would convert the integers to string. But his answer is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

`file.write` only accepts a single string argument, but in your code `file.write(key, ' : ', value)`, you are passing in three arguments. Change it, as the others mentioned, to a single string input.

E.g. @mrblewog's answer

```
file.write(f'{key} : {value}')
```

You can check out this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/file_write.htm) for a simple explanation

Comment: Yes, thank you for your contribution! This worked perfectly!